# STATUS_NOT_FOUND as "An unexpected internal error" in signtool.exe

Tags: code-signing, signtool

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25432267/476371). Alas, that question is about a different CA (Symantec) and uses a different hardware token (from Safenet) and while the provided solution(s) there match the error code, the circumstances of my case don't (among other things the smartcard I was provided with doesn't seem to register its own provider under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Cryptography\Providers`).

I am using an Open Source code-signing certificate from certum.pl. I am using the `signtool.exe` from the Windows SDK `10.0.18362.0` and I am seeing the following error (with `signtool sign /v /debug`):

```
signtool.exe sign /v /debug /a /i Certum /ph /du "https://my.url" /d "short description" /fd sha256 /tr "http://timestamp.digicert.com" /td sha256 "mysoftware.exe"
The following certificates were considered:
    Issued to: Open Source Developer, ...
    Issued by: Certum Code Signing CA SHA2
    Expires:   ...
    SHA1 hash: ...
    Issued to: Open Source Developer, ...
    Issued by: Certum Code Signing CA SHA2
    Expires:   ...
    SHA1 hash: ...
After EKU filter, 2 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 1 certs were left.
After Issuer Name filter, 1 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 1 certs were left.
The following certificate was selected:
    Issued to: Open Source Developer, ...
    Issued by: Certum Code Signing CA SHA2
    Expires:   ...
    SHA1 hash: ...
Done Adding Additional Store
Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-1073741275/0xc0000225)
SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
```

The error code `0xC0000225` matches exactly the following `NTSTATUS`:

```
//
// MessageId: STATUS_NOT_FOUND
//
// MessageText:
//
// The object was not found.
//
#define STATUS_NOT_FOUND                 ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000225L)
```

... which makes perfect sense, given `HRESULT` codes as used by `signtool.exe` and the underlying infrastructure map 1:1 to `NTSTATUS` (of course *if* a facility code is given, `HRESULT` codes exist which have no name in `ntstatus.h` ... what I mean is the layout of `HRESULT` and `NTSTATUS`).

Alas, this doesn't tell me anything, since a lot of things may not be found at any given time ... as of this writing I am still trying to narrow it down on my own using ProcMon. For the failing attempt I am seeing 592 `NAME NOT FOUND` results in ProcMon, which should correspond to the above `NTSTATUS` code; most of them for registry keys and values.

---

Here's the full `signtool` command line again:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x64\signtool.exe" sign /v /debug /a /i Certum /ph /du "https://my.url" /d "short description" /fd sha256 /tr "http://timestamp.digicert.com" /td sha256 "mysoftware.exe"

... and yes, I verified that it's really using that `signtool.exe` ... in fact I tried with x86 and x64 with full paths for good measure (my actual script wraps some of the complexities and prepares the environment to adjust `PATH` to be able to call `signtool.exe` without its full path).

Strangely enough it works when signing with SHA1 digests like so:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x64\signtool.exe" sign /v /debug /a /i Certum /ph /du "https://my.url" /d "short description" /t "http://timestamp.digicert.com" "mysoftware.exe"

(differences are the missing `/fd sha256` and `/td sha256` as well as `/t` instead of `/tr` for the timestamping service URL, i.e. different protocol)

The version of the proCertum CardManager software is 3.2.0.156, details as per the following screenshot:

[image: proCertum CardManager software version 3.2.0.156]

(It's the latest version available from the Certum website at the time of this writing.)

---

I meanwhile tried also with the `signtool.exe` (x86 and 64 respectively) from:

- Windows 8.1 SDK
- Windows 10.0.17763.0 SDK

... same results and I am puzzled as to how I can resolve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the problem was an option that was not correctly set by default (the name suggested that it only applies to EV certificates, but it appears that it *also* applies to ones with SHA2 digests). Thanks to the Certum support folks!

[image: proCertum CardManager Options dialog]

I highlighted the relevant option.

Also note, that I had to

1. quit the application (from TNA aka "system tray")
2. start the application *elevated* from its program folder
3. check the checkbox
4. hit the OK button
5. dismiss the (success) message box
6. reboot

... when I had previously tried without elevation the process failed. And yes, I saw the "shield" icon, but I had assumed that the application contains the logic to perform the elevation (it doesn't).

When I retried signing after a reboot, it was no longer the proCertum CardManager prompting for the card's PIN, but Windows. And signing worked like a charm.

**NB:** there were still no entries underneath `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Cryptography\Providers` after these steps.