# Singing ClickOnce Application with EV Code Siging

Tags: clickonce, code-signing, codesign

I have an EV code signing certificate from ssl.com and I'm trying to sign a ClickOnce application to get rid of the warning messages when the users install the application, however, I wasn't able to do it so far. The certificate is properly configured as I can use SignTool.exe to sign setup.exe, but this is not enough, as I apparently need to sign the .manifest and .deploy files using Mage.exe as per this [MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/walkthrough-manually-deploying-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2022). However, with the private key stored on the hardware token, I get the following result for this command (note, I'm using Mage version 4.8.3928.0 and Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10):

```
mage -Update "MyApp.exe.manifest" -CertHash "xxxxxxx" -csp "Microsoft Smart Card Key Storage Provider" -KeyContainer xxxxxxx

This certificate does not contain a private key - "xxxxxxx"
This certificate cannot be used for signing - "xxxxxxx"
```

Note that in this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/91e74b1f-d82e-4313-86b0-f481264fbc84/mageexe-net-47-hardware-security-module?forum=csharpgeneral), TanyaSolyanik from Microsoft says that Mage.exe version 4.7 only supports certificates with private key in store, and that 4.7.1 will fix this. I’m using version 4.8 but it’s still not working.

I think I read every article I can find by Google, and every relevant stackoverflow question that I could find, but nothing helped.
Note that some questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432267/using-ev-certificate-with-clickonce) talks about using the built in signing feature in Visual Studio publish, however, when I try this, I cannot find my EV certificate in the list of certificates in the store, because it does not have a private key.

Comment: Re: the second part of your question, I had a similar issue when VS wouldn't find an installed certificate. Try to delete and re-import the certificate into the store.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else ran into this, I gave up trying to sign my ClickOnce application with the EV code signing certificate. I added a setup project and deployed my application using an MSI installer.
The assembly was signed using a post build event, and the MSI and setup.exe were signed in the setup project post build events. This worked perfectly and my final application was installed without the unknown publisher and other UAC warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this topic [Automate Extended Validation (EV) code signing with mage.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865770/automate-extended-validation-ev-code-signing-with-mage-exe/77838801#77838801).

Short version: MageUi.exe supports you to find the correct configuration.

In my case, the wrong CSP name was assigned. Instead of "eToken Base Cryptographic Provider" (correct in signtool.exe) "SafeNet Smart Card Key Storage Provider" worked.